# How to communicate android to nodejs to my sql?

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, database-connection

is communicating from android to node.js to mysql the same way like communicating with php? Could you please suggest some tutorials to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android you can perform the server side tasks by using the web services.

Web services is a medium to communicate between server and client. Here in android client is our android app and we will be needed a web service to communicate with database which will do all the transaction on server side and this web service only will generate some response and we will consume this response into our android app.

The web service is like a program which can accept some inputs and generate some output on the basic of input parameters and functionality which is written inside this program. This program can understand specific format and generate the response in some specific format. Format means like XML, JSON.

So the flow will be like.

We will call the web service from our app and provide the input parameters. 
The web service will run and generate some output in JSON.
And then we will consume the web service response in our android app.

Hope this will help you.

https://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Comment: can you provide a link where connection from android to mysql in nodejs server is made.I mean an example.

Comment: okay... i'll provide.. if i found any.. i did in my project but that i can not share here ... i'll try to find out some example buddy... :)\